# Group by clause not working in DB2 (sql code -119)

Tags: sql, group-by, db2

I want to get the amount of results for each day of the past week. Unfortunately, I got this error for the query:

> An expression starting with "APP_ID" specified in a SELECT clause,
>   HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY
>   clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause
>   with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified..
>   SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, DRIVER=3.67.27

The query:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(created), app_id 
FROM Annotation 
WHERE app_id = 1 AND (created < CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS) 
GROUP BY DAYNAME(created) ORDER BY created
```

The problem has something to do with the `GROUP BY` statement. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is pretty clear -- `appid` is in the `SELECT` but not the `GROUP BY`.  The solution is that you need an aggregation function.  I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(created), COUNT(*)
FROM Annotation a
WHERE app_id = 1 AND (created < CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS)
GROUP BY DAYNAME(created)
ORDER BY MIN(created);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use group by, then every column must either by in your group by statement, or aggregated.

`select col1, col2, 'same-for-every-row', sum(col3) as col3_sum, avg(col4) as col4_avg
from schema.table
group by col1, col2`

This works because col1 and col2 have been grouped by, but every other column has some aggregation to know how to group up all the values.

Your current statement won't work, because although you've grouped by date, you haven't specified how to group all of the rows for app_id, you need to specify that they should be grouped by summing or averaging or finding the minimum or aggregating in some other way, all of the values in that group.

The exception being a column that's created using a string, 'same-for-every-row', this won't need to be aggregated as it's the same every time.